Geopandas polygon within OR matches identically?
I sub-polygons (1,2,3,4,5 in image below) for which I need to flag true or false if they are either within or identical to a boundary polygon (GROUP A in image below)


For examples sake - the output should return as polygons 1-4 being within or identical to group A, and polygon 5 as not meeting that criteria.
So far I have used the geopandas.within() function which picks up polygons 2-4, but not polygon 1 because there are no vertices within the group A polygon, only along the border.
sub_polygons['within_group_flag'] = sub_polygons.within(groupA)

Does anyone have a solution that would identify both situations and populate a column in sub-polygons with true/false?


covers()/  covered_by() ? You can check
https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/geoseries.html#binary-predicates for a list of binary predicates.
